# Ignore certain scripts for JSDOM

Tags: javascript, jsdom, error-detection

I am building sets of tools to monitor certain web pages.  These pages have a combination of internally written javascript and external tools and scripts.   When jsdom.env runs across a javascript error it fails out with an error, as it should.

When I see a failure for internally written scripts I can work with the developers to get them fixed, but for external items it is more difficult.

Is there a way to tell jsdom to simply ignore errors in certain scripts, either on an individual basis, or by domain, or some other way?

Comment: Try this. Create a test page to open with jsdom. Make it load a script (using `<script src="...`). In that script put `throw new Error('kaboom');` in it. Below that `<script>` tag put another `<script>` tag with this code in it `window.test = true`. Once you get into the `done` callback, what value do you get for `window.test`?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Use a regex filter in the [SkipExternalResources](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom#external-resources) option.